# java vs C# web service clients

Tags: c#, java, web-services

I've been doing java web services for a couple of years here and there and I've always heard about the ease of use of C#.Net Soap-WS clients. I just tried it out and I have to say, I am a bit jealous - having had to fight through generated code with both Axis and CXF (try using Axis in OSGi or with NTLM authentication...or just look at the horrible generated code, or try using dynamic URL's in CXF).

Is there a java analog to the simplicity of .Net (soap) web service clients? Ideally, you would add the URL to your project, just like you add a service reference in Visual Studio and the behind the scenes code would be setup for you. Is this possible? If not, why not - what is C#.Net doing differently?

Comment: SOAP is by far more popular in MS world.

Comment: Producing web services in enterprise java is quite simple, but I think the client side is still a ways off.

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck with the [Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-web-services) . Its not quite as easy as C#'s toolset, but when you get down to it, its all just reading a WSDL and generating client adapters. Visual studio lets you do that with the push of a button where with Spring, you can use Ant/Maven to generate your proxies/adapters. Most IDE's will do this for you too (see Randolpho's answer, I know IntelliJ Idea does).

Edit: I believe [SoapUI will do this](http://www.soapui.org/) as well, although I haven't used it so I can't tell you how well that works

Comment: I've used SoapUI - it isn't too bad, but still leaves much to be desired. I haven't really got right down to it and tried the Spring way, but I will try to soon. +1

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will create a Java web service client very similar to a Service Reference.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M3/tutorials/WebServiceClient.html

Comment: Yeah, this is part of WTP & the Eclipse enterprise build - I quit using this as it generates Axis, and to my knowledge has not been updated to work properly with CXF; at least not out of the box.

Comment: I see; I totally misunderstood your request.